# form_for nested resource says 'no route found' in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have the following routing:

```
resources :pages do
    resources :logos do
      member do
        post 'vote'
      end
    end
  end
```

Then I have a view that is rendered in /pages/:page_id/logos, that looks like this:

```
  <ul>
  <% @logos.each do |logo| %>
    <li>
      <%= image_tag(logo.url) %>
      <%= form_for([logo.page, logo], url: {action: "vote"}, :method => :post) do |f| %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"vote", :page_id=>"95", :controller=>"logos"}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
form_for [logos.page, logo, :vote], method: :post
```

or, it may be that the action comes first in the array

```
[:vote, logo.page, logo]
```

Pardon that I don't have to look it up again.

Comment: You need ot answer with more confidence - or don't.  I would only work with this answer if I had no other idea.